# Match and remove all spaces inside brackets pattern

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I want to match all spaces that are inside every `[[]]` in a string so I could use a replaceAll method and remove them.

Example input: `text text [[ ia asd ]] [[asdasd]] dfgd dfaf sddgsd [[sss aaa]]`

Expected output: `text text [[iaasd]] [[asdasd]] dfgd dfaf sddgsd [[sssaaa]]`

I thought of this: `\[\[(\s*?)\]\]` which should match all spaces that are between double brackets but it doesn't match anything.

I also tried several other solutions to similar problems but non seemed to work.

Any clue what else could be used?

Comment: You might want to use a lookahead and lookbehind operator. This is what I have, although I'm not sure where to go from here: (?<=\\[\\[) *(?=\\]\\])

Comment: I've got sort of a crummy answer.  If you are just looking for quick and dirty one time thing: `\[\[\s*(\w*)\s*(\w*)\s*(\w*)]]` replace with `[[$1$2$3]]`  it just doesn't scale.  But you can copy paste more `\s*(\w*)` in there with more $1 values.   https://regex101.com/r/vLwYkU/1  if this works I can write up in nicely as an answer :)

Comment: This is best done with regex replace with a callable in the replacement part, e.g. `text.replace(/\[\[.*?]]/g, (x) => x.replace(/\s+/g, ''))` in JavaScript. There are ways to remove whitespace with a plain text replacement if you use .NET or PCRE. Is it Java?

Comment: Without checking opening `[[` a quick one would be to use a lookahead: [`\s+(?=[^\]\[]*]])`](https://regex101.com/r/75sNEp/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble but that could cause some serious bugs if a `]]` will be in the string, then all previous spaces will be removed.

Comment: Due to use of the negated class it can not "skip backwards" over any `[`. The only "issue" I can think of if `[[` would be missing (but wouldn't that be correct anyway?). If you like, update [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/BErIVw/1) with cases that fail.

Comment: @shinzou Though to mention that it's not working if any single `[` or `]` inside `[[`...`]]` (which the selected answer can deal with). It's a good answer anyway. :) However for any other strings without brackets inside it could be a short and efficient alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering it is Java, you can use

```java
String result = text.replaceAll("(\\G(?!^)|\\[\\[)((?:(?!]]).)*?)\\s+(?=.*?]])", "$1$2")
```

Or, another approach is matching all substrings between `[[` and `]]` and then removing any whitespace inside the matches:

```java
String text = "text text [[ ia asd ]] [[asdasd]] dfgd dfaf sddgsd [[sss aaa]]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[.*?]]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(buffer, m.group().replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
}
m.appendTail(buffer);
System.out.println(buffer.toString());
```

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/lbu8Ia).

The first regex means:

- `(\G(?!^)|\[\[)` - Group 1 (`$1`): either `[[` or the end of the preceding successful match
- `((?:(?!]]).)*?)` - Group 2 (`$2`): any char other than line break chars, zero or more but as few as possible occurrences, that does not start a `]]` char sequence
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=.*?]])` - immediately to the right, there must be any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, and then `]]`.